# Swift How combine to Numeric Type

Tags: swift

I am kind of new to Swift, and wonder how to create a combined types.

```
typealisa Number = Int & Float & Double
```

Isnt work.

```
public protocol Number {} ;
extension Int : Number {} ;
extension Double : Number {} ;
extension Float : Number {} ;
```

When you try

```
var a : Number = 1 ;
var b : Number = 2 ;
a * b
//Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to two 'Number' operands
```

In TS, this cloud be simple as

```
type Number = Number = Int & Float & Double
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Just an FYI, this is often referred to as a "Union Type". If you search for that, you may find answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to re-invent the wheel, there is already protocol which you need: [`Numeric`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric).

Its description is very self-descriptive:

> A type with values that support multiplication

And the types like `Int`, `Double`, ... already conform to it.

---

Anyway, if you wonder why your code doesn't work, it's because protocol provides interface and tells what implementations should contain and what is possible to do with them.

So, if you need that your `Number`s can be multiplied, you need to describe it in protocol's declaration.

```
protocol Number {
    static func * (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}
```

... now you described that every `Number` can be multiplied by other `Number`.

Comment: Protocol 'Numeric' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements, If I try to make a struct Number, how should I do??

Comment: Above model, If I use it for type, like var a : Number = 0 ; Protocol 'Number' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements. will occur, since its not a struct